# How to create two DropDownList from differents model in the same view using ASP MVC SQL and EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005. I am using Entity Framework with a code-first approach.

I have a model Profile_Ga with it Views(Index,Create,...).

I created a DropDownList in the Index of this model to load the IDs (ID_Gamme).

I want now to load the IDs of another table (another model which is Poste) in the Index of Profil_Ga.

But always this error appears :

> DataBinding: 'MvcApplication2.Models.Profile_Ga' does not contain a
>   property with the name 'ID_Poste'.

This is the Controller of Profile_Ga :

```
namespace MvcApplication2.Controllers
{ 
    public class ProfileGaController : Controller
    {
        private GammeContext db = new GammeContext();

        //
        // GET: /ProfileGa/

        public ViewResult Index(Profile_Ga profile_ga, Poste poste)
        {
            ViewBag.ID_Gamme = new SelectList(db.Profil_Gas, "ID_Gamme", profile_ga.ID_Gamme);
            ViewBag.ID_Poste = new SelectList(db.Postes, "ID_Poste", poste.ID_Poste);
            return View(db.Profil_Gas.ToList());


        }
```

and this is what I add in the Index :

```
<%:Html.Label("Gamme :")%>
       <%: Html.DropDownList("ID_Gamme", new SelectList(Model, "ID_Gamme", "ID_Gamme ")) %>


        <%:Html.Label("Poste :")%>
       <%: Html.DropDownList("ID_Poste", new SelectList(Model, "ID_Poste", "ID_Poste ")) %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is spot on. The Model doesn't contain `ID_Poste`.

You are storing `db.Postes` into the ViewBag but the model being passed to the view is just `db.Profil_Gas` as in this part: `return View(db.Profil_Gas.ToList());` - this won't contain `db.Postes`.

As you want to show two separate things the best approach would be to create a new **ViewModel** class that contains both things like this.

**View Model**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    // The two drop-down lists
    public List<Profile_Ga> Profile_Gas { get; set; }
    public List<Poste> Postes { get; set; }

    // Used to store selected items
    public int SelectedProfile_Ga { get; set; }
    public int SelectedPoste { get; set; }
}
```

**Then in your Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(Profile_Ga profile_ga, Poste poste)
{
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
    viewModel.Profile_Gas = db.Profil_Gas.ToList();
    viewModel.Postes = db.Postes.ToList();
    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
    string debug = string.Format("You selected Profile: {0} and Poste: {1}", viewModel.SelectedProfile_Ga, viewModel.SelectedPoste);
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

**Finally in your View**

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("SelectedProfile_Ga", new SelectList(Model.Profile_Gas, "ID_Gamme", "NameToShow")) %>
<%: Html.DropDownList("SelectedPoste", new SelectList(Model.Postes, "ID_Poste", "NameToShow")) %>
```

Then you simply replace `NameToShow` with the property you want to show in the drop-down box. Then, when you submit the form the **ViewModel** will be passed back with the value of the drop down boxes (as shown in code example). Place breakpoint on debug in `HttpPost` item to check the values are right and then you should be good to go!

Comment: Problem of the creation of controller ! Need to define a Key ! What can i do ?

Comment: @anouar - You can use your existing view and controller. Simply swap out the code you had in your OP with the code I have provided. You do not need to create a new view / controller.

Comment: Oh yes ! I understand already that lol ! the problem now is about the SelectList in the viewmodel/ error : 'selectlist cannot be used with type arguments'

Comment: @anouar - Sorry, I did my answer without a computer. You need to make them lists and then convert to SelectList in the view. I've altered my answer and included ViewModel, Controller and View code. Also shown how you can show one item "NameToShow" while storing a different value. So, Fred Bloggs would return ID 6 etc.

Comment: Ok No problem :) but there is a few errors : First the statment 'return viewModel' it is not accepted--> Cannot implicitly convert type 'MvcApplication2.ViewModels.FlowViewModel' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult'
Second, in the View : Model.MyGames ---> MyGames is underlined in Red,,,I don't know why

Comment: @anouar - I've given the full example including how to capture the return values from the drop-downs. I am guessing at your type and variable names so if you see any red lines it means my guess at Profile_Ga and Poste might be wrong but just replace with actual types.

Comment: yes ! I change that,,,I didn't copied stupidly! However, after Building the project,,,It's OK
But the first error of return viewmodel still !

Comment: No, I didn't mean any offence! I was just making sure it wasn't something like that. My mistake, updated code so the HttpGet action now returns View(viewModel); Try new code now and let me know.

Comment: It's Ok Belogix lol I wasn't bleaming you,,,I am just explained what I did :)
I try your new solution, but there is a new error in the line of  viewModel.Postes = db.Postes.ToList();  which is :
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'FlowViewModel' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �FlowViewModels� is based on type �FlowViewModel� that has no keys defined.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29738/discussion-between-belogix-and-anouar)

Comment: Good luck, Belogix. I am leaving this in your capable hands!

Comment: Thanks @SamLeach - Think we've been working in parallel! This is now getting into realms of Entity Framwork and other stuff so we'll see where it goes!

Comment: @Belogix what a luck :(( I have VS 2010 and the projrct is done with VS 2012

Comment: @anouar - I sent a message end of Friday. Check the chat-room we were in and add any comments in there please.

Answer (score 1):

Your view model is `Profile_Gas` so you cannot do

```
<%:Html.Label("Poste :")%>
       <%: Html.DropDownList("ID_Poste", new SelectList(Model, "ID_Poste", "ID_Poste ")) %>
```

You need to create a view model that encapsulates both `Profile_Ga` and `Poste`

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Poste> Postes { get; set; }
    public List<Profile_Ga> Profile_Gas { get; set; }
}
```

and return this view model from your controller.

```
public ViewResult Index(Profile_Ga profile_ga, Poste poste)
{
    return new ViewModel
            {
                 Postes = db.Postes.ToList(),
                 Profile_Gas = db.Profil_Gas.ToList();
            }
}
```

So your view will look something like

```
<%:Html.Label("Gamme :")%>
       <%: Html.DropDownList("ID_Gamme", new SelectList(Model.Profile_Gas, "ID_Gamme", "ID_Gamme ")) %>


        <%:Html.Label("Poste :")%>
       <%: Html.DropDownList("ID_Poste", new SelectList(Model.Postes, "ID_Poste", "ID_Poste ")) %>
```

Comment: Problem of the creation of controller ! Need to define a Key ! What can i do ?

Comment: When I will create the controller,,,I choose as template "Controller with read/write actions and views" using Entity Framework. So I have to choose also the model class and the data context class.
When, I did an error message which oblige to define a key to my model choosed.
This case appeared to me before when i created the others models,,,but I fix defining a Key to each model.
However now, I have only 2 listes in the model and 0 attributs ! what key I will define ?

Comment: Your model is a new model that you define that has your types as properties.

Comment: so I create an empty Controller ?

Comment: SelectList is not accespted also ! 'selectlist cannot be used with type arguments'

Comment: I try it and I try many things (like ICollections,...).Infact when I use the List,,,the error deplace to the Controller and here is : Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MvcApplication2.Models.Poste>'

Comment: It's telling you what's wrong. See my revised answer above. Don't use SelectLists in the view model, just regular lists.

Comment: Ok thanks but it still a few errors : First the statment 'return viewModel' it is not accepted--> Cannot implicitly convert type 'MvcApplication2.ViewModels.FlowViewModel' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult' Second, in the View : Model.Profile_Gas and Model.Postes ---> Profile_Gas and Postes are underlined in Red,,,I don't know why